# I am not able to export audios on my desired folder processed by pydub

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pydub

I am working on a script that split audios by 1 second, which performs its task well until i try to export all those files on different directories rather than source file directories, how can I make this script export file wherever I want.

```
from pathlib import Path
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.utils import make_chunks
# directory ='files'
directory = r'C:\\Users\Siyam-Fahad\Desktop\\files'
files = Path(directory).glob('*')
for file in files:

    myaudio = AudioSegment.from_file(file, "wav")
    chunk_length_ms = 1000
    chunks = make_chunks(myaudio, chunk_length_ms)
    print(chunks)

    for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        chunk_name = f"{file}{i}.wav"
        print("exporting", chunk_name)
        chunk.export(f'C:\\Users\Siyam-Fahad\Desktop\\pycode'+ chunk_name, format="wav")
```

Error log:

```py
File "C:\Users\Siyam-Fahad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", 
line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile fd = open(fd, mode=mode) OSError: [Errno 22] 
Invalid argument: 'C:\\Users\\Siyam-Fahad\\Desktop\\pycodeC:\\Users\\Siyam-Fahad\\Desktop\\files\\mixkit-crickets-and-insects-in-the-wild-ambience-39.wav0.wav'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not given the path correctly, did you miss backslash at some point in the `directory`.
This the correct way `directory = r'C:\\Users\\Siyam-Fahad\\Desktop\\files'`

Comment: Yassin here might be right! But the error is saying there's an OS error so try it first @Android

Comment: Yassin thanks for your answer but it's not my issue, I am having an issue with export(), my script running well if I don't pass any path on the export function like "        chunk.export(chunk_name, format="wav")", but whenever i pass path its throw error

Comment: `chunk.export(f'C:\\Users\Siyam-Fahad\Desktop\\pycode'+ chunk_name, format="wav")` in this line you're giving two paths these two paths start with c:\\Users...  when you're adding `chunk name` you're given a non-existent path

Comment: Try to remove `chunk_name`  **or** `f'C:\\Users\Siyam-Fahad\Desktop\\pycode` because you're adding two paths

Comment: tried, but now facing this "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Siyam-Fahad\\Desktop\\pycode'
"

Comment: So you're using Windows, you need to change Permission using chmod command I suggest using **bash terminal** or **Ubuntu for Windows**.